# Creating generic struct for a queue that allows for changing type of data stored

Tags: c

I'm working on an assignment in C and am looking to create two different queues of a max size, one to store integers, and another to store strings. I am trying to implement them as a circular array, and am trying to use a general struct to do so. This is what I have for the struct so far, but I'm wondering how I can ammend this so that I don't have to make two totally different structs for integers and char pointers.

```
#define SIZE 10
typedef struct intQueue{
    int array[SIZE];
    int front;
    int rear;
}

typedef struct charQueue{
    char *array[SIZE];
    int front;
    int rear;
}
```

Would the solution be to use a void pointer for the array? Will this give me trouble when I am dequeuing items and returning them later? Or would I just have to make sure that the return type of my dequeue function would be a void pointer as well?

Comment: If you need a generic structure in C, consider `void*`.

Comment: In general, yes, a pointer queue can queue anything, integers, strings, lists, threads, processes, server instances, application instances:)

Comment: Other options, have a look at [Writing a safe tagged union in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42844423/3422102)

Answer (score 0):

The old school way would be to do

```
typedef struct {
    void* data;
    size_t item_size;
    int front;
    int rear;
} queue_t;
```

And then you'd do create the queue either with caller allocation or with dynamic allocation inside the queue ADT (`malloc(SIZE * item_size)`). Optionally with an enum to keep track of the type used.

You'd then get a specific index with `((unsigned  char*)data)[i * item_size]` or some similarly evil-looking code. It's rather cumbersome overall to do generic programming in C. There are other options with opaque pointers or C11 `_Generic` + macros, but that makes for fairly complex code too.